# Sending Unicode text messages SMS/Arduino

Tags: c#, c++, arduino, sms, gsm

I have tried everything and have exhausted myself in the process.
I can send normal text SMS messages with no problem.

I am setting everything I need to when the message sends.

```
if (! sendCheckReply(F("AT+CMGF=1"), ok_reply)) return false;
if (! sendCheckReply(F("AT+CSCS=\"UCS2\""), ok_reply)) return false;
if (! sendCheckReply(F("AT+CSMP=17,168,0,8"), ok_reply)) return false;
```

I am encoding my Unicode chars properly, however my fona comes out like this:

```
+ Response: +OK SEND NUMBER
+ Response:
+ Sending: 6616634660
+ Response: +OK SEND MESSAGE
+ Response:
+ Sending: 005B004E00450058002000560041004C00450054005D00200053004D005300200073006500720076006500720020006900730020006E006F0077002000720075006E006E0069006E0067002E
+ Response: AT+CMGF=1
+ Response: OK
+ Response: AT+CSCS="UCS2"
+ Response: OK
+ Response:
+ Response: AT+CSMP=17,168,0,8
+ Response: OK
+ Response: AT+CMGS="6616634660"
+ Response:
+ Response: ERROR
+ Response: -ERROR Failed sending message
+ Response: +OK READY FOR NEXT COMMAND
+ Response:
```

As soon as AT+CMGS gets sent, it errors out.
Even if I supply the phone number in UCS2 HEX format, it does the same thing.

I am assuming the format/encoding isn't as expected.

Here is the Unicode encoding (pulled from another Stackoverflow post solution)

```
  Public Function UnicodeStr2HexStr(strMessage As [String]) As [String]
        Dim ba As Byte() = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(strMessage)
        Dim strHex As [String] = BitConverter.ToString(ba)
        strHex = strHex.Replace("-", "")
        Return strHex
    End Function

    Public Function HexStr2UnicodeStr(strHex As [String]) As [String]
        Dim ba As Byte() = HexStr2HexBytes(strHex)
        Return HexBytes2UnicodeStr(ba)
    End Function

    '================> Used to decoding GSM UCS2 message  
    Public Function HexBytes2UnicodeStr(ba As Byte()) As [String]
        Dim strMessage = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(ba, 0, ba.Length)
        Return strMessage
    End Function

    Public Function HexStr2HexBytes(strHex As [String]) As Byte()
        strHex = strHex.Replace(" ", "")
        Dim nNumberChars As Integer = strHex.Length / 2
        Dim aBytes As Byte() = New Byte(nNumberChars - 1) {}
        Using sr = New StringReader(strHex)
            For i As Integer = 0 To nNumberChars - 1
                aBytes(i) = Convert.ToByte(New [String](New Char(1) {Chr(sr.Read()), Chr(sr.Read())}), 16)
            Next
        End Using
        Return aBytes
    End Function
```

When I take out all the unicode stuff, set the CSMP back to 17,167,0,0

SMS Text messages work (text-only)

I am guessing the CSMP settings are NOT correct, but I am just throwing wrenches in the dark at this point... can someone help?

Comment: Does your code talk directly to the GSM device, or is the Arduino doing this? In the latter case, is the software on the Atmega/Arduino capable of handling Unicode strings and not limited to (zero-terminated) single-byte strings? Also, your code example in the question is missing the crucial code snippet where you actually transmit the the AT+CMGS command (including any Unicode conversions...)

Comment: C# code talks to the Arduino through their fona software; the software on the Arduino shield is fully capable of UCS2. Asking it 'AT+CSCS?' confirms the latter.

Comment: So, the response to the 'AT+CSCS' command is not from the actual GSM device, but from the Arduino?

Comment: There are two pieces of software.... The C# system which queues the messages and sends them to the Arduino running fona... and the fona software, which talks directly to the GSM device. All the AT+... commands are issues directly to the GSM device (from fona/arduino)

Comment: To answer your question more directly.... Every AT response comes directly from the GSM modem.

Comment: Well, i checked the documentation Adafruit provides for the fona, as well as the Adafruit_Fona github repo. No mention of UCS2 mode anywhere. From what i can tell from the code in your question so far, there should be no issue... weird...

Comment: UCS2 isn't a fona function, it's a GSM modem function... If the chip supports it, then you can use it. And the chip said "good to go"; but not in that terminology. I just think my CSMP flags are wrong, but I could spend a long time and basically have a 1 in 254^254^254^254 chance in guessing it correctly.

Comment: You set the charset to UCS2, now the destination phone number must be UCS2 encoded.  That's why the command containing the phone number failed.